# Get availability status of Azure resources

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I want to get the availability of azure resources. Right now I am using: 
`GET "https://management.azure.com/{}/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/
availabilityStatuses/current?api-version=2015-01-01"` api for which I need to get jwt.
Is there any Python SDK way to do the same thing as in

[`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/monitoring?view=azure-python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/monitoring?view=azure-python)

I want to use something similar to:

```
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=client_id,
        secret=secret_key,
        tenant=tenant_id,
        cloud_environment=AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD
    )

client = MonitorManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
```

Rather than generating jwt token and running the API, I wish to use pythonic way where I can use client_id, secret, tenant and cloud_environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SDK as of now, but seeing your issue I created an issue in the Azure SDK repo:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/8343

We actually generate SDK from a service meta-description, and we have access to this one, so we should be able to generate this SDK for you.

Please follow-up on the Github issue ticket

(I work at MS in the Azure SDK team)